# difference cmake .. and make

Tags: cmake, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,

what is the difference between cmake .. and make ?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/164306/difference-cmake-..--and-make/) by [Dante](https://answers.ros.org/users/12521/dante/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-05-13

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-05-13**:
if you just googled a little bit about it. CMake makes it easy to link all the dependencies and generates a Makefile, used by make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a general question and isn't really relevant to ROS or robotics.

There are a number of good answers on sites such as StackOverflow and blogs on the internet:

- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280515/what-are-the-major-differences-between-makefile-and-cmakelist
- http://prateekvjoshi.com/2014/02/01/cmake-vs-make/

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2